What we know about the function in Fefferman's Theorem
In Fefferman's many papers on Whitney's theorem he, amongst other things, constructs the existence of a smooth function $F$ which extends a function $f$ on a (say) finite set $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ which agrees with the jet "data" of f.   Moreover, by work of Bierstone and Milman we also know how many 'combinations' of jet information one needs to make the construction go through.
This is constructed, somehow (the papers are at times extremely long), by locally searching through spaces of polynomials which agree with $f$ near each datum in $E$.  However, how is $F$ glued together from these polynomials?

Specifically, I'm asking: if $N:=\#E\in \mathbb{N}_+$, where $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\{p_x\}_{x\in E}$ is a set of polynomials of degree at-most $m\in \mathbb{N}_+$, then is the extension $F\in C^{m,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ constructed in (one of) Fefferman's papers a piecewise polynomial?  If so, can it be written as
$$
\sum_{x\in E}\, \tilde{p}_x(\cdot)\,\phi_x(\cdot)
$$
for some smooth compactly supported functions $\{\phi_x\}_{x\in E}$ forming a partition of unity of some fattening of $E$?  If so, do we know what these $\phi_x$ look like?

I'm not familiar with the details of the Fefferman-Klartag papers, but it is written here that the Fefferman-Klartag extension is piecewise rational, not piecewise polynomial (see problem F16). It poses as an open question whether the extension can be taken to be piecewise polynomial.
The definition of piecewise polynomial used in this document is different than the one in your question. In that document, piecewise polynomial means there is a decomposition of a cube containing $E$ into subcubes such that the extension is a polynomial on each subcube, but your question is a little different: it is posed in terms of a partition of unity.
Different papers by Fefferman and others in this literature (which I am more familiar with) did construct an extension which is closer to the form you describe. In this paper, the extension is constructed using a hierarchical decomposition that ultimately is similar to what you describe. Assume that the set $E$ is contained in the unit cube $Q_0$. A label $\mathcal A$, which is a subset of the set of multi-indices of order at most $m$, is assigned to $E$. $E$ carrying the label $\mathcal A$ is a soft, quantitative, $C^m$ version of the claim that $E$ lies in the vanishing set of the ideal $I_{\mathcal A} = (x^\alpha : \alpha \in \mathcal A)$. An order relation is assigned to multi-index sets, and the extension operator is constructed by induction on $\mathcal A$. If $E$ carries the label $\mathcal A$, $Q_0$ is decomposed into dyadic cubes $\{Q\}_{Q \in \mathcal W}$ such that $E \cap 3Q$ carries an easier label than $\mathcal A$ on $3Q$. The cubes in this decomposition have good geometry, in if $Q, Q' \in \mathcal W$ and $Q \cap Q' \neq \emptyset$, then $\delta_Q \leq 2 \delta_{Q'}$, where $\delta_Q$ denotes edge length. For each cube $Q$, a polynomial $P_Q$ is found, and then an extension $F_Q$ is computed for $f - P_Q$ on $3Q$ for each $Q \in \mathcal W$, using the inductive hypothesis. Then the extension has the form $$\sum\limits_Q \phi_Q (P_Q + F_Q).$$
The function $F_Q$ can be ensured to have negligible norm, but the polynomials $P_Q$ must be carefully chosen to be mutually compatible on abutting cubes. Most of the work of this long paper is dedicated to establishing this.

Thanks for the details and links, its great!  I was reading through the answer this week but I have a question, what is $\phi_Q$ here in your notation?

${\phi_Q}_{Q \in \mathcal W}$ is a partition of unity with respect to the decomposition $\mathcal W$ of $Q_0$. Such partitions are pretty standard in theorems of this type. It should have the following properties: (i) $\text{supp}(\phi_Q) \subset 1.1 Q$, (ii) $|\partial^\alpha \phi_Q(x)| \leq C \delta_Q^{-|\alpha|}$ for all $\alpha$ with $|\alpha| \leq m$ and all $x$, where $C$ is a constant depending on $m$ and $n$ only, and (iii) $\sum_Q \phi_Q \equiv 1$ on $Q_0$. Property (i) implies in particular that $x \in \text{supp(\phi_Q)}$ for at most $C$ many $Q$

Ah interesting, so any POU with respect to $\mathcal{W}$ having these properties would do the trick?

Yep, similar to the POU used in the classical Whitney extension theorem
